# Declare a friend function but define it in an other namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend

```
   class A
    {
    private:
        A(int x, int y);
        friend A* CreateA(int x, int y);
    };

    namespace B
    {
        A* CreateA(int x, int y)
        {
            return new A(x, y);
        }
    }
```

The compiler gives me the following error: calling a private constructor of class 'A'.
Is it possible to have a friend function definition in an other namespace than the declaration?

edit:
This is the solution:

```
class A;

namespace B
{
    A* CreateA(int x, int y);
}

class A
{
private:
    A(int x, int y);
    friend A* B::CreateA(int x, int y);
};

namespace B
{
    A* CreateA(int x, int y)
    {
        return new A(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlanStokes I don't think this will work because it's kind of circular. `B::CreateA` relies on `A::A(int, int)`, but `A` relies on `B::CreateA`, etc. ad infinitum.

Comment: This should be reopened. OP wasn't asking **why** this is happening. OP was asking if friend function definition can exist in another namespace.

Comment: @erip It's fine. Forward declare `A`, then forward declare `CreateA`, then define `A`, then define `CreateA`.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me! I added `class A;` and `namespace B { A* CreateA(int x, int y); }` above my code.

Comment: @erip And the answers to the duplicate show that it can, and how to achieve it.